# Uncaught runtime errors : Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am facing this issue for 2 days now I cant't get it how to can fetch the data. I check= the type of it is scheme it is showing object.  I used Object.keys method but still geting the same error.
here is image of my data structure. Here is only showing two but can be more and the paymentData is an array. Please tell me how can i do this.

[image]

### schemeAPIslice file

```
export const schemeApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getSchemeOfUser: builder.query({
            query: () => ({
                url: `${SCHEME_API_URL}`,
                method: "GET",
                credentials: "include",
            }),
            keepUnusedDataFor: 5,
            providesTags: ["Schemes"],
        }),
        createScheme: builder.mutation({
            query: (data) => ({
                url: `${SCHEME_API_URL}/scheme_started`,
                method: "POST",
                body: data,
                credentials: "include",
            }),
            invalidatesTags: ["Schemes"],
        }),
    }),
});

export const { useGetSchemeOfUserQuery, useCreateSchemeMutation } = schemeApiSlice;
```

### Dashboard.js

```
const { data } = useGetSchemeOfUserQuery();
<div className='container'>
                <SchemeData schemes={data?.schemes} />
            </div>
```

### schemedata component

```
const SchemeData = ({ schemes }) => {
    console.log(schemes);
    console.log(typeof schemes);

    console.log(typeof JSON.stringify(schemes));

    return (
        <div>
            <h5>Scheme List</h5>
            <ul>
                {Object.keys(schemes).map((item, i) => (
                    <li className='py-5' key={i}>
                        <span>{schemes[item]}</span>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Each `schemes[item]` is an object, which isn't valid JSX when rendered like `<span>{schemes[item]}</span>`. What specifically are you wanting to render from each element object in `schemes`? For example `schemes.map(item => <span>{item.user}</span>)`.

Comment: schemes is an array and you can't use Object.keys here. In JS the typeof Array is object

Comment: @Shahzaib I checked with `console.log(typeof schemes)` it showing me object. At first I used as a array.map then i got this error after checking  i use the Object.keys method

Comment: @DrewReese First I want to render key value pairs then after I will add the design

Comment: @DrewReese Sometimes I dont get value of schemes it shows undefined if I refresh or reload

Comment: Right, but the ***values*** themselves are ***objects*** and can't be directly rendered as JSX. As for the issue of `schemes` sometimes being undefined, provide a fallback prop value, e.g. `const SchemeData = ({ schemes = [] }) => { ...}` so it's at least mappable when an undefined value is passed. What exactly are the key-value pairs you are trying to render?

Comment: @DrewReese I am adding more details please check I used reduxtoolkit. to fetch the data from backend

Comment: Narayan, what specifically from each `schemes` element object do you need to render? `schemes[item]` is the object that isn't valid JSX.

Comment: @DrewReese these is the first time i facing the issue I don't know how can I solve this problem I just want to render all the data in my dashboard I have a thought of rendering the payment data as a card but right now my concern is to render the data without getting error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only significant issue with the code is that `schemes` is an array of objects and the code is trying to render the raw element objects directly.

```
{Object.keys(schemes).map((item, i) => (
  <li className='py-5' key={i}>
    <span>{schemes[item]}</span> // <-- schemes[item] is object!
  </li>
))}
```

This is functionally equivalent to mapping the `schemes` array directly (*`Object.keys(schemes)` is just an array of the array indices*):

```
{schemes.map((item, i) => (
  <li className='py-5' key={i}>
    <span>{item}</span> // <-- item is object!
  </li>
))}
```

Since `item` is still an object you will need to pick out the properties you want to actually render. For example, `item.user` or `item.wallet`.

Example:

```
{schemes.map((item, i) => (
  <li className='py-5' key={i}>
    <div>User: {item.user}</div>
    <span>Wallet: {item.wallet}</span>
  </li>
))}
```

If you are wanting to render the `item.paymentData` this is yet again another array of objects, each array element needs to be mapped to valid JSX. For example, a list of monthly payments.

```
<ul>
  {schemes.map((item) => (
    <li className='py-5' key={item._id}>
      <div>User: {item.user}</div>
      <span>Wallet: {item.wallet}</span>
      <ul>
        <p>Payments</p>
        {item.paymentData.map(({ amount, month_name }, i) => (
          <li key={i}>{month_name} - {amount}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

If the `schemes` prop value is sometimes undefined then you can either provide a fallback prop value:

```
const SchemeData = ({ schemes = [] }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h5>Scheme List</h5>
      <ul>
        ...
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Or pass a fallback value to `SchemeData`:

```
<SchemeData schemes={data?.schemes ?? []} />
```